# Mouse movement in console application and ssh

Tags: c++, linux, ssh, debian, console-application

I'm trying to build an application that will run on a display less raspi. The application should be started via ssh. And it should capture mouse movement. (think robot needing said mouse to navigate)

SDL needs a window, and that's not really on option for ssh and console.
gpm only returns key press.

Any idea?

Edit : The mouse is on the raspi. The app will be started via ssh, but that's only to help debug.

Comment: so your looking to see the mouse movement through ssh? or are you wondering how to get mouse movement on the program running on the raspi? you could just send the coordinates through ssh in intervals or when the mouse moves, or you can check this out to get mouse movement http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Game/Q_24118835.html

Comment: ya the mouse is on the raspi. I would to see movement done with the mouse, on the remote host via ssh.
Well, at the end mouse movement will be used to run logic in a deamon that has to be started via ssh. So everything is on the raspi.
Since the raspi has no display, and we have to activate the program via deamon/ssh, so creating a windows via sdl is not an option.

So we could say that I want a daemon to have access to mouse movement. 

Or transfer mouse mouvement to joystick movement. SDL can capture that without a window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

access the mouse on a lower-level, e.g. via the *HID*-layer, accessing directly the relevant `/dev/input/event*` device, e.g. using [libhid](http://libhid.alioth.debian.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You could poll the mouse position in intervals, then send the mouse position through ssh to the raspi if the position has changed (send new position minus last position)

```
POINT lastpos;

void SendMousePos()
{
    POINT currpos;
    if (GetCursorPos(&currpos))
    {
        if(currpos != lastpos)
        {
            SendMovementToRaspi(currpos.x - lastpos.x, currpos.y - lastpos.y);
            lastpos = currpos;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The mouse is on the raspi, not on the host. The ssh is only to debug, stop and start the program.
Thanks